# How to load a trained BlazingText model

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, fasttext

I have  trained a text classification model using blazingText on AWS sagemaker, I can load the trained model and deploy an inference endpoint

```
model = bt_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, endpoint_name=endpoint_name, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge', serializer=JSONSerializer())
payload = {"instances": terms}

response = model.predict(payload)

predictions = json.loads(response)
```

and it's working fine,  now I need to load the model's `bin` file using an `entry_point` in order to do some logic before and after predictions in the `input_fn` and `output_fn`.

I extracted the `bin` file from the `model.tar.gz` and I can load it, but I get `Segmentation Fault` when I try to run a prediction

```
from gensim.models import FastText
from  gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model, load_facebook_vectors

model=FastText.load('model.bin')
model.predict('hello world')
```

As per blazingText [documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html)

> For both supervised (text classification) and unsupervised (Word2Vec)
> modes, the binaries (*.bin) produced by BlazingText can be
> cross-consumed by fastText and vice versa. You can use binaries
> produced by BlazingText by fastText. Likewise, you can host the model
> binaries created with fastText using BlazingText.
>
> Here is an example of how to use a model generated with BlazingText
> with fastText:
>
> #Download the model artifact from S3 aws s3 cp s3://<YOUR_S3_BUCKET>//model.tar.gz model.tar.gz
>
> #Unzip the model archive tar -xzf model.tar.gz
>
> #Use the model archive with fastText fasttext predict ./model.bin test.txt

but for some reason it's not working as expected

Comment: What version of FastText are you using? Are you building your own container?

Comment: Can you try using the latest version of FastText 0.9.2, if you continue to face an issue I suggest opening up a Support Case.